# Using Javassist library to detect runtime type of a method caller

Tags: javassist

I know that javassist.expr.MethodCall.getClassName() returns the compile time type of the method caller because it depends on bytecode analysis. I am wondering if there is an efficient way to get the actual runtime type of the method caller with javassist using some trick or through code inspection.

Here is a simple example to make things clearer.

```
public interface Animal {

    public void eat();
}


public class Dog implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("dog eating");   
    }

}


public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Animal a = new Dog();
        a.eat();
    }
}
```

In this example, I would like to find a way to get a "Dog" object as the method caller for the method "a.eat()"

Answer (score 0):

From the javassist.expr.MethodCall you can easily get the runtime class that has called this method:

```
CtClass ctc = javassist.expr.MethodCall.getMethod().getDeclaringClass();
```

Once you have the Javassist representation of the class that called this method that contains everything you need about this class.

PS if you really need a Dog instance you can use reflection taking the name by the CtClass, e.g.:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(ctc.getName());
Dog dog = ((Dog)clazz).newInstance();
```